# Any Powershell command or c# method to re-submit a failed job in Azure Data lake

Tags: azure-data-lake

Need to re-submit a failed job from Powershell or using c# ADL SDK. Any PS command or .Net ADL SDK method to re-submit a ADL failed job using job id?

Answer (score 0):

To resubmit a job, simply run:

```
$previousJob = Get-AdlJob -Account <account> -JobId <job id>

$script = $previousJob.Properties.Script

Submit-AdlJob -Account <account> -Name <name> -Script $script
```

You can also grab other fields to re-use in `$previousJob`, and optionally re-use those in `Submit-AdlJob`.